# Sort ASC and DESC column after import in the Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I use:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet1!1:1000"), 
"SELECT Col" & 
JOIN(", Col", 
MATCH(
{"COL_NAME"},
IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet!1:1"),0)))
```

to import a Column from Sheet2 and I need some help to sort for A-Z and Z-A in that Query after I get the date from Sheet2

I try manual but remain the same, I also use "order by Sort Column" but seems something wrong.

Here I have the exact exemple: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/172RDg2yrk04mciL7Tmi3PWBBV8AY7AII43jFX_HcB64/edit#gid=0

I need to get data from Sheet2 to Sheet1, because the Sheet2 is dynamic...and not always "timestamp" is in the same position in the Sheet2. And I need to sort "timestamp" in Sheet1.

Hope I make myself clear :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the exact nature of your problem. Would you please provide some same data as well as an example of the result of the quest AND an example of the sort that you want. BTW, are you familiar with the `order_by` clause for `QUERY`? [doc ref](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#order-by)

Comment: Your timestamp on Sheet 2 is returning as text, not as a date. Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: Yes, I wanted like a text...and need to sorted by Z-A..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new condition at the end of QUERY by concatenating with "&". In your MATCH I'd change that 1 with a 0 if you need an exact match of the column header:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("172RDg2yrk04mciL7Tmi3PWBBV8AY7AII43jFX_HcB64", "SHEET2!1:1000"), 
"SELECT Col" & 
JOIN(", Col", 
MATCH(
{"timestamp"},
IMPORTRANGE("172RDg2yrk04mciL7Tmi3PWBBV8AY7AII43jFX_HcB64", "SHEET2!1:1"),0))
&" order by Col1 desc",1)
```